# How to have 2 gesture detectors both trigger onScale/pan inside a stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app currently has a function to splitscreen control 2 images side by side and they can move individually. My goal is to add another Listener/Gesture Detector on the top so that it can also scale.
However only one works, Im not sure how to make both gesture detectors get detected.

The reason for doing this instead of just put everything into 1 detctor is because in that case, you cannot scale when 1 finger is on each splitscreen (since they're separate detectors.

Code:

```
Stack(children:[Row(children: [
              //primary Gesture Detector
              GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onTapDown: (details) {
                  //init tap
                },
                onTapUp: (details) {
                  //split screen code
                },
                onPanStart: (details) {
                  //pan
                },
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  //panning
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  scaleStart = false;
                  reportController.setLastScale(1.0);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: reportController.horizontalSplit
                      ? reportController.horizontalSplitMainWidth
                      : constraints.maxWidth,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              //secondary Gesture Detector
              GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onTapDown: (details) {
                  //init tap
                  tapDownLocation = details.globalPosition;
                },
                onTapUp: (details) {
                  // check if its a click
                  // its a click if user move distance is <5% of width
                  Offset moveDistance =
                      details.globalPosition - tapDownLocation;
                  if (moveDistance.distance <= constraints.maxWidth * 0.05) {
                    //horizontal split
                    reportController.setHorizontalSplit(true);
                    reportController
                        .setHorizontalSplitWidth(details.globalPosition.dx);
                    setState(() {});
                  }
                },
                onPanStart: (details) {
                  scaleStart = true;
                },
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  if (scaleStart) {
                    //change offset
                    reportController.setSecondaryOffset(
                        reportController.secondCurOffset + details.delta);

                    //set boundary
                    setBoundary(constraints);
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  scaleStart = false;
                  reportController.setLastScale(1.0);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: reportController.horizontalSplit
                      ? constraints.maxWidth -
                          reportController.horizontalSplitMainWidth
                      : 0,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Scaling Gesture Detector
            GestureDetector(
              onScaleStart: (details) {
                //scale
              },
              onScaleUpdate: (details) {
                //scale code
              },
              onScaleEnd: (details) {
                //scale
              },
            ),])
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way, where you can add two Gesture detectors in one Screen, where both are listening. What you can do is, to recognize two fingers or one finger. If there are two fingers get the position of the first one and scale the image under it. If there is only one finger, do what you want to do with one finger